# JQuery not working on first click, but working after it

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
function getBlock2(EUID, MID, I, ESTS)
{   
      $('.new-exam').on('click', function() {
        $('.new-exam').removeClass('new-exam');
        $(this).addClass('new-exam-hover');
        $('.tab-item-hover').addClass('tab-item');
        $('.tab-item').removeClass('tab-item-hover');
      });
      $('.tab-item').on('click', function() {
        $('.new-exam-hover').addClass('new-exam');
        $('.new-exam').removeClass('new-exam-hover');
        $('.tab-item-hover').removeClass('tab-item-hover');
        $(this).addClass('tab-item-hover');     
      });

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: './exam/x/exams_ajax.exe.php',
        data: { EUID : EUID, MID : MID, I : I, ESTS : ESTS },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
        $('.block2').html(data);
      }

  }); return false;
}
```

On the first click, the ajax part works, but the remove/addClass one doesn't until I click again.

I can't seem to figure out why, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is this wrapped in document . ready?

Comment: How you call your function getBlock2(EUID, MID, I, ESTS) ?
On click event?

Take out `$('.new-exam').on('click', function() {` this part out of function and it will work

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or snippet of your code

Comment: Why you are writing the `click` events inside a function?

Comment: Yes, i call the function in an <a> onclick, I've tried taking out that part, it still doesn't work. It's a bit complex in order for me to create a jsfiddle, but I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest add `document.ready` as suggested by others and then check if you are doing in below order.

1. First include jQuery library
2. Include js file which has `getBlock2` function defined
3. Include js file which is calling `getBlock2` function

As a best practice, always refer your js files at the end of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your JavaScript to the end of the document body or enclose your jQuery code inside a `document.ready` block

```
$('.new-exam').on('click', function() {
    $('.new-exam').removeClass('new-exam');
    $(this).addClass('new-exam-hover');
    $('.tab-item-hover').addClass('tab-item');
    $('.tab-item').removeClass('tab-item-hover');
  });
  $('.tab-item')
```

If this is called before the body is loaded, your page won't have any  `new-exam` or `tab-item` things yet.

Comment: When I try to enclose it in a document.ready block I get an error "getBlock2 is not defined". Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I'm not very experienced with javascript.

Comment: You must have some other code that calls getBlock2 before it exists. Understanding timing in JavaScript takes some work, but to get started, always put *all* your JavaScript inside the `document.ready`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the problem.

I was loading the function before including the JQuery library, that's why I was getting an error when I was trying to get it into a `document.ready` block.

I've changed the order moved just the next part into a `document.ready` block and now it works fine!

```
$('.new-exam').on('click', function() {
    $('.new-exam').removeClass('new-exam');
    $(this).addClass('new-exam-hover');
    $('.tab-item-hover').addClass('tab-item');
    $('.tab-item').removeClass('tab-item-hover');
  });
  $('.tab-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.new-exam-hover').addClass('new-exam');
    $('.new-exam').removeClass('new-exam-hover');
    $('.tab-item-hover').removeClass('tab-item-hover');
    $(this).addClass('tab-item-hover');     
  });
```

Thanks for your help.